# How can I loop over all inner values of an arbitrary deep nested list?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a `deep_list` which might be something like

```
deep_list = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2} for _ in range(2)]
```

or

```
deep_list = [[{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2} for _ in range(42)] for _ in range(10)]
```

or

```
    deep_list = [[[{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2} for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(42)] for _ in range(10)]
```

So a list of (lists of)* dicts.

I would like to iterate over them in a way

```
for index_tuple, element in elements_of(deep_list):
     print((index_tuple, element))
```

For the first example, it would print

```
((0, ), {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
((1, ), {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
```

For the second example, it would print something like (I don't care about the order)

```
((0, 0), {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
((0, 1), {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
...
```

For the third list it would be something like

```
((0, 0, 0), {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
((0, 0, 1), {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
...
```

My approach would be to write a recursive traversing function ... but is there something nicer / directly built-in into Python?

Comment: The recursive approach would definitely be the most concise, straightforward way to do it.

Comment: I am not aware of anything. Consider changing the desired output of the first variation to `((0,) {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})` for consistency points?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I changed it. Thank you :-)

Comment: Would your `deep_list` be consistently deep? Because the title says *arbitrarily* but the three examples are *consistently* deep; all `dicts` at the same, although initially unknown level. For example, is this also a possibility: `[{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}]]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, it would be consistently deep. (Thanks for the example - that is not possible in my case)